# How to move pages around and rename them while not breaking incoming links from external sites that still use the poorly formed URLs

Tags: iis, asp-classic, url-rewriting

**update**

[image]

**Here is the situation:**

I'm working on a website that has **no** physical folder structure.  Nothing had been planned or controlled and there were about 4 consecutive webmasters.

Here is an example of an especially ugly directory

- `\new\new\pasite-new.asp`

most pages are stored in a folder with the same name as the file, for maximum redundancy.

- `\New\10cap\pasite-10cap.asp`
- `\QL\Address\PAsite-Address.asp`

each of these [page directories]?  (I don't know what else to call them) has an `include` folder, the include folder contains the same `*.inc` files in every case, just copied about 162 times for each page directory.  The include folder was duplicated so that the 
`<!--#include file="urlstring"-->` would work correctly due to lack of understanding of relative paths, and the `#inclue virtual directive` or using `server.execute()`

Here is a picture if my explanation was lacking.

[image: directory structure]

---

**Here are some of my limitations:**

- The site is written in ASP classic
- Server is Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2 , IIS 6 (According to my resource)
- I have no access to the IIS server
- I would have to go through a process to add any *modules* or features to iis

---

What changes can I make that would allow me to move pages around and rename them while not breaking incoming links from  external sites that still use the poorly formed URLs?

**To make my question more specific.**

How can I move the file `10cap.asp` from `\new\10cap\` to a better location like `\` and rename the file to someting like `saveourhomescap.asp` and not break any incoming links and finally, not have to leave a dummy `10cap.asp` page in the original location with a redirect to the new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a lot of limitations and especially no access to the IIS server hurts. An ISAPI module for URL rewriting is not an option here (IIS) and equally a custom 404 page where you could read the referer and forward with a HTTP 301 won't work (IIS).

I would actually recommend you to go through the process and let them install:

- An ISAPI URL rewriting module

or if that doesn't work (for any reason):

- Let them point the HTTP 404 of your web to a custom `404.asp`, read the referer and redirect with a HTTP 301 (Moved Permanently) to your new location.

If none of this is an option for you, I can think about another possibility. I haven't actually tried that so I'm not 100% sure if it will work, but in theory it sounds good ;)

You could make in your [`global.asa`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525316.aspx) in the [`Session_OnStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524776.aspx) event a `Response.Redirect` or change the header of your response to a HTTP 301. This will actually only work for new users and not fix real 404 errors. Sorry, for the pseudo code, but it's a while ago that I had anything to do with classic ASP and I think you'll get what I mean ;)

```
sub Session_OnStart

    ' here should be a Select Case switch or something like that 
    Response.Redirect("newlocation.asp")

    ' or if that will work, this would be better (again with switch)
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
    Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://company.com/newlocation.asp"

end sub
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think isapirewrite will work.  Since it is a relatively easy installation process.  I really need to be able to find some good examples of how to write the httpd.conf / .htaccess files I would Need.

Comment: I'll concede the bounty to whoever can get me explicit instructions on how to setup the redirects for the different scenarios I have.

Comment: Okay I've begun testing using Isapi Rewrite 3.  Sadly the url remapping works, but it is breaking alot of the includes and ../javascript/file/references/.  ughhh....

Comment: Haha! I've been able to get this thing working as required.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: You're welcome. Just out of curiosity, what was your final solution? The Isapi Rewrite module?

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that's a lot of limitations to deal with.

Can you setup a custom error page? If so you can add some code into a custom error page that would redirect users to the new page. So maybe you create a custom 404 page, and in that page you grab the query string variable and based on that send the user to the correct "new" page. That would allow you to delete all of the old pages.

Here is a pretty good article on this method: [URL Rewriting for Classic ASP](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/URL_Rewriting_%28Classic_ASP%29)

Comment: That may be possible; I tried one version of that yesterday from a different site; maybe I didn't give it enough time.  I couldn't get it to work at all.

Comment: I followed the site instructions and it works. but I think I'm missing some of the finer points.  Do I need to create an asp page for each value in the sBaseURLList variable? See my code in OP

Comment: Sorry, what sBaseURLList variable are you referring to? I see a variable named aURLParts.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using URL Rewrite for that, see the following blog about it, in particular "Site Reorganization":

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx

For more info about URL Rewrite see: http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

Comment: Not sure you read my question all the way.  Does URL Rewrite work with IIS6 and asp classic? I don't have a web.config file to modify.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, ULR rewrite only works with IIS 7 and above. It does indeed work with any framework, like Classic ASP, ASP.NET, PHP, Static files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ISAPIRewrite since it's classic ASP + IIS6
http://www.isapirewrite.com/

They have a lite version which is free, probably good enough for your use.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^.*/home/?$ /home/pasite-home.asp [nc]`  why won't this work?  shouldn't this take any url entered in the address bar to the pasite-home.asp page?

Answer (score 0):

urlrewrite will only work if you can install a dll on the server

one of these articles will help

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=qRR&q=url+rewrite+classic+asp&btnG=Search&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g-m1

basically you have to point 404 errors to an error page which will parse the incoming querystring / post info and redirect user to correct location with incoming parameters added.

variations on that theme will be found in the examples fro google.